# anime js - reset entire timeline (remove all previously added animations)

Tags: javascript, animation, anime.js

I can add animations to anime timeline using the `timeline.add({parameters})` function. Is it possible to remove all the previously added animations and reset the whole timeline?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the timeline by calling the `restart` method:

```
const tl = anime.timeline({
  duration: 400,
  easing: 'easeInOutQuad',
})

tl.add({
  targets: '.box',
  rotate: 360,
  translateX: {
    value: 400,
    delay: 400,
  }
})

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    tl.restart();
});
```

Comment: you made my day :)) I like tl.restart()